# Got java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException, http call failed after <number> milliseconds for url, for multiple scenarios

Tags: java, eofexception

I have, for example, this simple scenario:

```
Scenario: Validate user ID
  Given path usersUrl + randomEmail + '/validate'
  When method GET
  Then status 200
  And match response == read('schemas/details.json')
```

During the execution it fails on step When method GET, with the exception:
ERROR com.intuit.karate - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException, http call failed after 1159 milliseconds for url: https://qa.company.com/
When method GET
http call failed after 1159 milliseconds for url: https://qa.company.com/users/korey36@gmail.com/validate

We have about 300 endpoints. About 250 works fine. But there are some endpoints that don't and we can't find the root cause of such behavior.

We have proxy and it works for another scenarios.
This scenario(and another failed scenarios) works fine in Postman and don't work in Karate framework.

I tried to talk with BE, and check requests to the server from Postman and Karate FW. Server receive the same requests. But Postman gets 200, Karate gets EOFException.

Tried to change request body, add headers, params and etc. nothing helps.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: We switched to another url and everything started to work fine. 
Definitely not karate issue.